# How to change Pivot Cache dynamically

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I am trying this approach to make code more dynamic for changing data source of pivots but its not working. I am trying to pass everything using variables as given

```
 Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("E:\QBR - EMEA\Refresh Files\Distri templates2\SOURCEDATA_EMEA Pack_MERGE.xlsb") 
            Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Data") 
            Set StartPoint = wks.Range("A2") 
            Set DataRange = wks.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)) 
    NewRange = wks.Name & "!" & _ DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) 
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _ PivotCaches.Create( _ SourceType:=xlDatabase, _ SourceData:=NewRange)
```

Comment: You can replace the hardcoded values with variables, which you can set programatically to whatever is needed.

Comment: Can you use `RANGE`-function and a `String` for the path and the filename?

Comment: can you please provide a example of how to do it ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to show an example of how to set a variable without knowing more about what you are trying to do.  E.g. how do you want to set the file path - via an InputBox, via the value of a cell, via a FileOpen dialog?  And how do you want to set the range - via an InputBox, via the value of a cell, via UsedRange, via a table, via ...?  (And those are just a few of the myriad ways you could make it "dynamic".)

Comment: I have filename, path, recordcount and sheetname in an variable and those values i want to pass in place of hardcoded values..
SourceData: value should be passed from a variable

Answer (score 0):

If you have `filename`, `path`, `recordcount` and `sheetname` in variables then you can change your code as follows:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "'" & path & "\[" & filename & "]" & sheetname & "'!R1C1:R" & recordcount & "C25" _
    , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
```

The original `SourceData` which you had (`"E:\QBR - EMEA\Refresh Files\Distri templates2\[SOURCEDATA_EMEA Pack_MERGE.xlsb]Data!R1C1:R500000C25"`) is just a string - and it can be replaced by any other code that ends up with a string in the correct format.

Comment: i am trying like this------
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("E:\QBR - EMEA\Refresh Files\Distri templates2\SOURCEDATA_EMEA Pack_MERGE.xlsb")
        Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Data")
        Set StartPoint = wks.Range("A2")
        Set DataRange = wks.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
        NewRange = wks.Name & "!" & _
        DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=NewRange)

Comment: @karambir Please add that code into your question - it is nearly impossible to read in a comment.

Comment: @ YowE3K please check in the question